# Rotate rectangle around center

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation, core-graphics

I am playing with [Brad Larsen's adaption](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2008/10/22/3-d-rotation-without-trackball) of the trackball app.
I have two views at a 60 degree angle to each other and was wondering how I get the rotation to be in the center of this (non-closed) rectangle?

In the images below I would have liked the rotation to take place all within the blue lines.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Code (modified to only rotate around x axis):

```
#import "MyView.h"

//=====================================================
// Defines
//=====================================================

#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(degrees) \
    (degrees * (M_PI / 180.0f))

//=====================================================
// Public Interface
//=====================================================

@implementation MyView

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    transformed = [CALayer layer];
    transformed.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.5f);

    transformed.frame = self.bounds;
    [self.layer addSublayer:transformed];

    CALayer *imageLayer = [CALayer layer];
    imageLayer.frame = CGRectMake(10.0f, 4.0f, self.bounds.size.width / 2.0f, self.bounds.size.height / 2.0f);
    imageLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(60.0f), 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    imageLayer.contents = (id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_0051.png"] CGImage];
    imageLayer.borderColor = [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor;
    imageLayer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
    [transformed addSublayer:imageLayer];

    imageLayer = [CALayer layer];
    imageLayer.frame = CGRectMake(10.0f, 120.0f, self.bounds.size.width / 2.0f, self.bounds.size.height / 2.0f);
    imageLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(-60.0f), 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    imageLayer.contents = (id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_0089.png"] CGImage];
    imageLayer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
    imageLayer.borderWidth = 2.0f;

    transformed.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    transformed.borderWidth = 2.0f;
    [transformed addSublayer:imageLayer];

    UIView *line = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.bounds.size.height / 2.0f, self.bounds.size.width, 2)];
    [line setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self addSubview:line];

    line = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.bounds.size.height * (1.0f / 4.0f), self.bounds.size.width, 2)];
    [line setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [self addSubview:line];

    line = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.bounds.size.height * (3.0f / 4.0f), self.bounds.size.width, 2)];
    [line setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [self addSubview:line];
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    previousLocation = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint location = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    //location = CGPointMake(previousLocation.x, location.y);

    CATransform3D currentTransform = transformed.sublayerTransform;

    //CGFloat displacementInX = location.x - previousLocation.x;
    CGFloat displacementInX = previousLocation.x - location.x;
    CGFloat displacementInY = previousLocation.y - location.y;

    CGFloat totalRotation = sqrt((displacementInX * displacementInX) + (displacementInY * displacementInY));

    CGFloat angle = DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(totalRotation);
    CGFloat x = ((displacementInX / totalRotation) * currentTransform.m12 + (displacementInY/totalRotation) * currentTransform.m11);

    CATransform3D rotationalTransform = CATransform3DRotate(currentTransform, angle, x, 0, 0);

    previousLocation = location;
    transformed.sublayerTransform = rotationalTransform;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
}

- (void)dealloc {
  [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: I am using Brad's code as is - tried various tests with changing anchor points but without luck

Comment: set the anchor point to mid and then rotate.

Comment: Can't see any rotation on the pictures. Did you set the sublayerTransforms m45 parameter?

Comment: Rotation is around the x axis so this is seen in image #2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `imageLayer.zPosition` of each of the triangle sides to the distance from the center of the triangle (which is an equilateral triangle in your case).

If `sideHeight = self.bounds.size.height / 2.0f;`
Then `distanceFromCenter = ((sideHeight / 2.0f) / sqrt(3));`

Also, when setting the rotation on the sides, you need to move them into their required positions (in your code they are hardcoded).

**Updated Code**

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    transformed = [CALayer layer];
    transformed.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.5f);

    transformed.frame = self.bounds;
    [self.layer addSublayer:transformed];

    CGFloat sideHeight = self.bounds.size.height / 2.0f;
    CGFloat distanceFromCenter = ((sideHeight / 2.0f) / sqrt(3));

    CGFloat sideC = sideHeight / 2.0f;
    CGFloat sideA = sideC / 2.0f;
    CGFloat sideB = (sqrt(3) * sideA);

    CALayer *imageLayer = [CALayer layer];
    imageLayer.frame = CGRectMake(10.0f, (self.bounds.size.height / 2.0f) - (sideHeight / 2.0f), self.bounds.size.width / 2.0f, sideHeight);
    imageLayer.transform = CATransform3DConcat(CATransform3DMakeRotation(-DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(60.0f), 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
                                               CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0, -sideA, -sideB));
    imageLayer.contents = (id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_0051.png"] CGImage];
    imageLayer.borderColor = [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor;
    imageLayer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
    imageLayer.zPosition = distanceFromCenter;
    [transformed addSublayer:imageLayer];

    imageLayer = [CALayer layer];
    imageLayer.frame = CGRectMake(10.0f, (self.bounds.size.height / 2.0f) - (sideHeight / 2.0f), self.bounds.size.width / 2.0f, sideHeight);
    imageLayer.transform = CATransform3DConcat(CATransform3DMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(60.0f), 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f),
                                               CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0, sideA, -sideB));
    imageLayer.contents = (id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_0089.png"] CGImage];
    imageLayer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
    imageLayer.zPosition = distanceFromCenter;
    imageLayer.borderWidth = 2.0f;

    transformed.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    transformed.borderWidth = 2.0f;
    [transformed addSublayer:imageLayer];

    UIView *line = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.bounds.size.height / 2.0f, self.bounds.size.width, 2)];
    [line setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self addSubview:line];

    line = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.bounds.size.height * (1.0f / 4.0f), self.bounds.size.width, 2)];
    [line setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [self addSubview:line];

    line = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.bounds.size.height * (3.0f / 4.0f), self.bounds.size.width, 2)];
    [line setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    [self addSubview:line];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use also other transformation (I think you'll need translation) and concatenate them with rotation. This example even scales the image, so you get a scaled, shifted and rotated layer:

```
CATransform3D translate = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(yourShiftByX, yourShiftByY, 0);
CATransform3D scale = CATransform3DMakeScale(yourRateX, yourRateY, 1);
CATransform3D rotate = CATransform3DMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(60.0f), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DConcat(CATransform3DConcat(rotate, scale), translate);
// the order is important: FIRST we rotate, THEN we scale and AT LAST we position the object

// now apply 'transform' to your layer
```

Answer (score 0):

you should make your imageView superView to show the perspective :

```
CATransform3D tranfrom = CATransform3DIdentity;
tranfrom.m34 = -1.0 / z;
imageView.superview.layer.transform = transfrom;
```